# I get a getControllerFields(Unknown Source) exception, javaFX?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, javafx, javafx-2

I get a `javafx.fxml.fxmlloader.getControllerFields(Unknown Source)` error, and thus a null pointer exception. I changed the structure of the project and edited the build path to contain different fxml files and stylesheets. Some fxml files have included fxml files as well.

I work in a project using JavaFX with a few others, and the weird thing is that a few of them have this error when executing the code. For me it works perfectly, with no error and all references in the code are changed according to the new project structure.

I do however use Java 8 while the others use Java 7.

I also checked the "classes" folder in the build path and everything seemed to be there.

The same problem is described here:

[link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/efxclipse/GlTC3Ln9dx4/XYpk5de0x4AJ)

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Actually, can you post the exception you're getting? You just posted a method name.